# Remove list from inside DF - Pandas - python

Tags: python, list, lambda, apply

I would like to take out from the list the data that is in the "typed" column

this my code:

```
cel = str(input('Qual o modelo? \nModelo:'))
    df['digitado'] =df.apply(lambda row: re.findall(cel,row['modelo'], flags=re.I),axis=1)
    df
```

Return:

[Return  (data frame)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fJe1F.png)

How would I take out "OT" from inside the [] and the empty [] leave nan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `re.findall` you can use `re.search` and `:=` operator:

The input dataframe:

```
         modelo
0         OT632
1  TCL 10 32 GB
2         OT639
3      Blade A3
```

Then:

```py
cel = "OT"

df["digitado"] = df.apply(
    lambda row: m.group(0)
    if (m := re.search(cel, row["modelo"], flags=re.I))
    else np.nan,
    axis=1,
)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
         modelo digitado
0         OT632       OT
1  TCL 10 32 GB      NaN
2         OT639       OT
3      Blade A3      NaN
```

---

Or without `:=` operator:

```py
def fn(row, cel):
    m = re.search(cel, row["modelo"], flags=re.I)
    if m:
        return m.group(0)
    return np.nan


df["digitado"] = df.apply(fn, cel=cel, axis=1)
print(df)
```